# OpenCV GUI applications (beyond highgui)

Tags: ros, opencv2, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, not sure if this is the right place for this, but here goes.

I was just wondering what's the best way to create more complicated OpenCV GUIs? I've made some simple stuff with highgui in python and now I want to  add more stuff that isnt' possible with just highgui. Can I use wxpython or pyqt or something to build off of a highgui application? I'm pretty new to python gui programming but so far it seems pretty simple. Or would I want to just make the whole application in wx or qt and not use highgui at all? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9528/opencv-gui-applications-(beyond-highgui)/) by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 307 on 2011-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is more of a general GUI question that can be asked on stackoverflow or any other GUI sites. but if you are specifically looking into UI libraries that can be integrated with ROS then I'd say Qt would be a better option. I was able to use Qt+OpenGL with ROS and render Kinect data in a QGL widget. Thanks

---

Originally posted by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) with karma: 284 on 2011-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) on 2011-03-22**:
Yeah I kind of figured but I thought maybe the audience here would be more focused. I am using it for a project that involves ROS but I guess this part is orthogonal to the ROS part.

**Comment by [ZsurzsaLaszlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2208/zsurzsalaszlo/) on 2013-06-05**:
blueskin, can you provide some tutorial links.If ti's possible then in C++ would be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've used OpenCV with Python/Tk. It's a bit messy (displaying images involves converting to PIL Images), but it works ok. If anyone is interested, I can write a tutorial on displaying ROS/OpenCV images in Python/Tk.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-03-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kalirajan M](https://answers.ros.org/users/12341/kalirajan-m/) on 2014-02-23**:
Hi Dan, did you tried python/Tk to show videos ? I have similar problem. Please visit this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930480/adding-gui-window-to-python-opencv2-program-with-pygtk3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just advertising that since `groovy` there's a tool call [rqt_image_view](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt_image_view#) that might do what OP wanted back then.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-01-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1